# How to avoid writing a grant with an advisor

Tags: advisor, ethics, funding

My postdoctoral adviser would like to co-write grants; however, I am at a stage in my career where I believe it would be better for me to write grants on my own. I will soon be faculty (in 5th of postdoc and on job market) and to my knowledge it is important to demonstrate that I have an independent research program and obtain funding to support it, rather than to gain funding with a former adviser, which will lead to question marks about how much of the ideas are mine. Cowriting grants would also limit my ability to use the same ideas that are based on my work in future independent grant applications. I have also been explicitly advised by others who have worked with my adviser that he has in the past written grants that very strongly build on the independent work/ideas of mentees. I know that my adviser can do this if he wants, but I don't want to help him do it or enlist as a co-I. Any suggestions for how to decline without ruffling feathers? I would like to maintain a good relationship with him.

Comment: Questions of the form "This is what I want to do, but  (I'm afraid to try, I think someone will be mad at me, etc.)" are essentially impossible to answer.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, why is it impossible to answer? There's one answer below already that seems reasonable. It's not of the form you suggest but rather, "This is what I want to do, but I don't know exactly how/need ideas." Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer #1: Talk to your adviser about these things. Tell him that you wonder how joint proposals will be perceived and get his perspective on things.

Short answer #2: Remember that it's easy to write proposals, and hard to write *winning* proposals. How are you going to learn what to say and not say in a proposal? The easiest way to learn this skill is to work with someone who has done this many times and who may have been on review panels many times. I have reviewed many a proposal by junior scientists in my lifetime where it is clear that they mean well, but have essentially no idea what to write in a proposal that can be funded. That may be your fate if you write by yourself, unless you have an experienced mentor who is willing to help you with it.

As far as demonstrating independence: If you're already on the job market, then this proposal will not be funded before anyone will look at your file anyway, so it's not going to make a difference one way or the other. It might make a difference come time for tenure, but that is so far in the future that you will have plenty of opportunities to demonstrate your independence till then. And for the moment, *any* funded proposal is better than no funded proposal.

Comment: I know how it will be perceived and how it likely will affect my career.  My goal is to try to build on my work independently of my adviser instead of letting it get subsumed into my adviser's program. I disagree with "any funded is better than no funded" if we co-write then he will get the credit and I will not be able to write the grant on my own and get credit. I don't have a large enough research program that I can just draw on other work for my grants. I have a fair amount of grant writing experience already. I'm looking for ideas for how to avoid co-writing without alienating him.

Comment: Believe me -- any funded proposal is better than no funded proposal.

Comment: Ok, but my reasoning is that it's not a question of funding vs no funding but funding with adviser vs funding independently (if possibly a bit later). Funding independently is more strategic, in my view. I have other resources that can support my grant writing at this point.

Comment: I don't see why "collaboratively funded now and independently funded later" is a problem. You have multiple years before the time of tenure, plenty of time to have more than one grant. Of course, there is also no reason why you can't have two grants at the same time -- one with your current adviser, and one by yourself. You seem to build all of these contradictions that aren't really there.

Comment: It's a problem because my adviser suggested ideas for a grant to cowrite that are squarely building on my work to date, which would preclude me from using these ideas in a future grant I'd write on my own. I shared these future directions ideas at a practice job talk once and he later brought them up as new ideas for a grant we could write, not acknowledging where the ideas came from and how using them in a co-written grant would affect my ability to apply for funding independently. And as a faculty I'm expected to apply independently right away and need to be able to build on my work.

Comment: I think you overestimate the degree to which using ideas in one proposal precludes you from using them in later ones. I think you also underestimate the degree to which you will have to come up with more than just one idea or research area in your future.

Comment: I appreciate this discussion and your points. The issue here is that given the very challenging funding climate, I don't want to do anything that will reduce my chances of getting a grant independently. I have built up a research program where there are very clear next steps. I don't think it's in my interest to take these next steps in a grant co-written with my current adviser. And of course I recognize that I have to generate more ideas in future -- that's not a worry -- but to start my independent career I need independent funding that will have to be based on the work I've done to date.

Answer (score 0):

In discussing this with your advisor, I suggest emphasizing your need to establish and demonstrate an independent program for faculty job-hunting. You can thank the advisor for all you have learned about grant-writing working with him during your postdoc, and tell him that you feel it is now time to put that learning to the test by independently writing a proposal based on your own research ideas.